# Shorthand if/else statement Javascript

Tags: javascript, shorthand

I'm wondering if there's a shorter way to write this:

```
var x = 1;
if(y != undefined) x = y;
```

I initially tried `x = y || 1`, but that didn't work. What's the correct way to go about this?

Comment: `x=y||x` works if you dont care about strict **undefined**

Answer (score 96, accepted):

```
var x = y !== undefined ? y : 1;
```

Note that `var x = y || 1;` would assign `1` for any case where `y` is falsy (e.g. `false`, `0`, `""`), which may be why it "didn't work" for you. Also, if `y` is a global variable, if it's truly not defined you may run into an error unless you access it as `window.y`.

---

As vol7ron suggests in the comments, you can also use `typeof` to avoid the need to refer to global vars as `window.<name>`:

```
var x = typeof y != "undefined" ? y : 1;
```

Comment: Yay for ternary operators. I'll try that out. Edit: Ah, okay. What about 'undefined'? Didn't seem to catch that.

Comment: What do you mean? The string `'undefined'` is a true value, and is not equal to the actual `undefined` value.

Comment: I meant, where the variable hasn't been declared at all. I know the string 'undefined' evaluates to a boolean true, but that's not what I was looking for.

Comment: When you say it "didn't seem to catch that", what do you mean? If you're dealing with a global variable that may not be defined, you'd probably want to use `window.y` (which will actually return `undefined`) rather than `y` (which could potentially cause an error).

Comment: I'd initially tried alerting the value of x, but nothing popped up. Further experimentation via console.log showed that y was undefined and it wouldn't even run the `||` statement.

Comment: See my edited comment above about using `window.y` instead of just `y`.

Comment: Yep, that does the trick; thanks. Still, I'm curious to know why y's `undefined` didn't evaluate to false and thus lead to x equaling 1. Edit: if I define `window` as `_`, I can then say `var x = _.y || `, which is as short as I could want. I'm only checking to see if y is undefined in this case so I'm not worried about falsy vs. false.

Comment: -1 — That ternary expression has **exactly** the same result as `x = y || 1`, since null, 0 and '' (empty string) are all `== undefined`. You should use `===` (if that's what the OP wanted).

Comment: @RobG - Updated to `!==` on matter of princple. That said, `false == undefined` is false. Try it (or just look at http://i.imgur.com/rHXiq.png).

Comment: its probably better to test for definedness using `typeof`

Comment: @Amber—you have your rep back.

Answer (score 24):

Another way to write it shortly

```
bePlanVar = !!((bePlanVar == false));

// is equivalent to

bePlanVar = (bePlanVar == false) ? true : false;

// and 

if (bePlanVar == false) {
    bePlanVar = true;
} else {
    bePlanVar = false;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
y = (y != undefined) ? y : x;
```

The parenthesis are not necessary, I just add them because I think it's easier to read this way.

Comment: Your parens are unbalanced (and also unecessary).

Comment: @Amber The moment you start using javscript shorthand, you are already saying you dont care about readability, so why bother with balanced parens?.

Answer (score 3):

Other way is using short-circuit:

`x = (typeof y !== 'undefined') && y || 1`

Although I myself think that ternary is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it that works, but may not be best practise for any language really:

```
var x,y;
x='something';
y=1;
undefined === y || (x = y);
```

alternatively

```
undefined !== y && (x = y);
```

Comment: Just noticed that this was already supplied by @AndreFigueiredo

Comment: Not exactly the same, thank you for your answer, though generally it's not good practice assign value in a condition.

Answer (score 0):

Appears you are having 'y' default to 1: An arrow function would be useful in 2020:

```
let x = (y = 1) => //insert operation with y here
```

Let 'x' be a function where 'y' is a parameter which would be assigned a default to '1' if it is some null or undefined value, then return some operation with y.

Comment: This is not what OP was asking for. You're suggesting that `x` becomes a function unless you immediately invoke that. Even then, this makes the code overly complex, since in JavaScript, default assignments can just be expressed with the `||` operator as @Nemesarial commented in OP or with the ternary operator in accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try if/else this shorthand method:

```
// Syntax
if condition || else condition

// Example
let oldStr = "";
let newStr = oldStr || "Updated Value";
console.log(newStr); // Updated Value

// Example 2
let num1 = 2;
let num2 = num1 || 3;
console.log(num2);  // 2  cause num1 is a truthy
```