# How to make shorter and readable comparison/logical lines to assign default values? in jQuery/JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, comparison, logical-operators

Consider the code at the bottom, inside a regular function, that checks if some argument was provided or not, and assigns a default value to a variable named message. If the argument is truthy or an empty string, It is simply converted to a string and is stored in the message variable, otherwise the type of argument will be stored in message.
I know it's possible to shorten if else statements to assign default values to variables, like:

```
var message = arguments[0] || jQuery.type(arguments[0]);
```

which if only the arguments[0] is truthy will be stored in message. But how to make an exception for an empty string which is a falsy value, without having to use a long if else statement?

```
if(arguments[0] || arguments[0] === '')
    var message = arguments[0].toString();
else
    var message = jQuery.type(arguments[0]);
```

Comment: Your first statement should use `&&`, not `||`.

Comment: oddly enough your "*long*" if else statement is easier to read/maintain than the ternary operator that you would need to do it in one line, and there would be no performance benefits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var message = ((arguments[0] || arguments[0] === '') ? arguments[0].toString() : jQuery.type(arguments[0]));
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for a shorthand if/else.  If so, you can find the answer to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864634/shorthand-if-else-statement-javascript).  Basically what you need is a ternary operator.

Excerpt below:

> `var x = y !== undefined ? y : 1;`

Comment: Or in the terms of your assignment: `var message = arguments[0] || arguments[0] === '' ? arguments[0] : jQuery.type(arguments[0]);`