# Javascript shorthand an if statement

Tags: javascript

What would be the shorthand equivalent of the following?

```
if (windowwidth >= 960){
        widthofwindow = 1;
    } else {
        widthofwindow = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Looking up "Javascript shorthand if statement" brings up lots of relevant results, the first one being http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864634/shorthand-if-else-statement-javascript

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use a ternary operator:

```
widthofwindow = windowwidth >= 960 ? 1 : 0
```

You could read that as

```
condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false
```

Comment: More precisely: The conditional operator (the only ternary operator in JS).

Comment: +1 - preempting the suggestion to do `widthofwindow = Number(windowwidth >= 960);` (ETA: 12 seconds too late). Might want to fix the name of the assignment target to `widthofwindow`.

Comment: Ternary exps are the way to go, but I usually try to either wrap the condition in parens (preferred), or drop whitespace in the condition, it can be easy to misread the statement otherwise. (Also, `widthofwindow =`)

Comment: You're right - I edited my answer to assign the value to  `widthofwindow`

Answer (score 4):

You may use some hacks (besides ternary operator) if you like

```
widthofwindow = Number(windowwidth >= 960);
```

> When using `Number(value)` expression the type conversion (value => Number) is performed and int this case if `windowwidth >= 960` is `true` it is cast to 1 and to 0 otherwise. Note that no `new` keyword is used since you don't want to create an object - you just want to cast one type to another.
>
> More information may be found here: [Number (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

or

```
widthofwindow = (windowwidth >= 960) * 1;
```

> This case (as well as `+(value)`) is an example of another approach to type conversion in JS. When you are multiplying (or using unary + sign) your boolean value also becomes a `Number` with respective value.
>
> You may found some information here: [JavaScript Garden](http://bonsaiden.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/#types.casting)

Comment: Or just `widthofwindow = +(windowwidth >= 960)`.

Comment: @FelixKling: forgot about this one:)

Comment: Oh, and even if it is obvious to us, maybe you should provide a quick explanation why/how this works. But you got my +1 anyways ;)

Comment: Needing to provide a quick explanation is, of course, exactly why this should never be done in actual code - even if the logic of it is good to know.

Comment: It works because `Number(true)` returns `1` and `Number(false)` returns `0`, as defined in `ToNumber` spec. See http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.3

Answer (score 0):

```
windowwidth = windowwidth >= 960 ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result = (condition) ? 'something' : 'somethingelse';
```

http://javascript.about.com/od/byexample/a/ternary-example.htm