# Shorthand for if-else statement

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have some code with a lot of if/else statements similar to this:

```
var name = "true";

if (name == "true") {
    var hasName = 'Y';
} else if (name == "false") {
    var hasName = 'N';
};
```

But is there a way to make these statements shorter? Something like `? "true" : "false"` ...

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery which is a DOM manipulation library for JavaScript.

Comment: Why are you using the word "true", rather than the boolean value `true`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shorthand if/else statement Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864634/shorthand-if-else-statement-javascript)

Comment: Not my question, sorry.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Using the [ternary `:?` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) <sup>[[spec]](http://es5.github.io/#x11.12)</sup>.

```
var hasName = (name === 'true') ? 'Y' :'N';
```

The ternary operator lets us write shorthand `if..else` statements exactly like you want.

It looks like:

`(name === 'true')`  - our condition

`?`  - the ternary operator itself

`'Y'` - the result if the condition evaluates to true

`'N'` - the result if the condition evaluates to false

So in short `(question)?(result if true):(result is false)` , as you can see - it returns the value of the expression so we can simply assign it to a variable just like in the example above.

Comment: It doesn't scale really well, look at my answer or @BenjaminGruenbaum answer

Comment: Several reasons, first of all you're mixing `"` and `'` for string literals which creates a false notion that they somehow represent different things. Second of all using the `==` operator [is frowned upon](http://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/1348195). Moreover, inline ternary blocks are harder to read than if statements (I prefer the original code) and don't pass code reviews in many companies. Also, your spacing is off.

Comment: @TusharGupta Asking someone to accept your answer is considered rude around here (see relevant meta threads). Moreover - OP will gain more by waiting for an hour or two and see what the community thinks about these answers before accepting any.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum i am just asking him to accept the answer but not mine he has his choice to select the answer.I just want he accept the answer of anybody n close the chapter

Comment: @TusharGupta you could keep your answer just as valid and fix the problems with it like mixing `"` and `'` for no reason, the inconsistent indentation, and so on. I think the downvotes relate to that and not the actual content, though I did not downvote myself so I can't really tell.

Comment: @TusharGupta Thanks for fixing it, I've made some clarifications (notably, formatting and adding links to the spec and to a reference). Feel free to revert any changes you don't like.

Comment: shouldn't it be **(name == 'true')** with only 2 equality symbols?

Comment: @Adam - using three symbols requires the values to be of the same *type* as well as the same *value* whereas using two symbols would do a conversion before checking the values:
2 == '2' would evaluate to true even though one is a string and the other is a number.
2 === '2' would evaluate as false because the two values are not of the same type.

Quick demo here if you want it :)

https://jsfiddle.net/c5fabevq/

Answer (score 30):

You can use an object as a map:

```
  var hasName = ({
        "true"  : "Y",
        "false" : "N"
  })[name];
```

This also scales nicely for many options

```
  var hasName = ({
        "true"          : "Y",
        "false"         : "N",
        "fileNotFound"  : "O"
  })[name];
```

(Bonus point for people getting the reference)

Note: you should use actual booleans instead of the string value "true" for your variables indicating truth values.

Comment: (Of course, the map doesn't have to be anonymous, if you name it, that's even better for readability in most non-obvious cases, readable code is more important than shorter code. While we all want to write concise code - it should never be in expense of clarity)

Comment: Nice solution! Wouldn't have thought of that. But i guess that using the index-operator will result in the same if/elseif construct in machine code.

Comment: @JoSo That depends on the implementation, but they would be equally fast on a clever run-time :) I use this construct in place of switch... case on strings a lot.

Comment: I aggree that a switch with strings would probably be equally fast / slow. In any other case (integers, booleans) the switch would be faster because the ALU of the CPU can handle it with ease. If you have to consider this in JavaScript - i do not know.

Answer (score 21):

Try this

```
hasName = name ? 'Y' : 'N';
```

Answer (score 20):

**?: Operator**

If you want to shorten `if/else` you can use `?:` operator as:

```
condition ? action-on-true : action-on-false(else)
```

For instance:

```
let gender = isMale ? 'Male' : 'Female';
```

In this case `else` part is mandatory.

I see this kinda short hand format use for `null`/`undefined` checking like:

```
const avatarName = user.firstname ? user.firstname : user.lastname;
```

However in this case you can simply use:

```
const avatarName = user.firstname ?? user.lastname;
```

or

```
const avatarName = user.firstname || user.lastname;
```

To see the difference check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61480993/when-should-i-use-nullish-coalescing-vs-logical-or) out

**&& Operator**

In another case, if you have only `if` condition you can use `&&` operator as:

```
condition && action;
```

For instance:

```
!this.settings && (this.settings = new TableSettings());
```

FYI: You have to try to avoid using if-else or at least decrease using it and try to replace it with [Polymorphism](https://refactoring.guru/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism#:%7E:text=In%20them%2C%20create%20a%20shared,depending%20on%20the%20object%20class.) or Inheritance. Go for being [Anti-If](https://francescocirillo.com/pages/anti-if-campaign) guy.

Answer (score 10):

Try like

```
var hasName = 'N';
if (name == "true") {
    hasName = 'Y';
}
```

Or even try with `ternary operator` like

```
var hasName = (name == "true") ? "Y" : "N" ;
```

Even simply you can try like

```
var hasName = (name) ? "Y" : "N" ;
```

Since name has either `Yes` or `No` but iam not sure with it.

Answer (score 5):

Most answers here will work fine if you have just `two` conditions in your if-else. For more which is I guess what you want, you'll be using arrays.
Every names corresponding element in `names` array you'll have an element in the `hasNames` array with the **exact same index**. Then it's a matter of these four lines.

```
names = "true";
var names = ["true","false","1","2"];
var hasNames = ["Y","N","true","false"];
var intIndex = names.indexOf(name);
hasName = hasNames[intIndex ];
```

This method could also be implemented using Objects and properties as [illustrated by Benjamin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18269354/903324).

Answer (score 1):

Try this method;

Shorthand method:

```js
let variable1 = '';

let variable2 = variable1 || 'new'
console.log(variable2); // new
```

Longhand method:

```js
 let variable1 = 'ya';
 let varibale2;

 if (variable1 !== null || variable1 !== undefined || variable1 !== '')
       variable2 = variable1;

console.log(variable2); // ya
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```js
var name = "true";
var hashname;
     name
      ? hashname = "Y"
      : !name
       ? hashname = "N"
       : ""

     console.log(hashname)
```