# Shorthand for if/else in javascript

Tags: javascript

I wrote the function to check if a given number is positive, negative, or zero. Is there a shorthanded way?

Is it possible to test the condition with map (using object to index the conditions)? i was inspired by second solution in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18269354/13782899) but not sure how it applies here.

```
const numCheck = (num) => {
  if (num == 0) {
    return "zero";
  } else {
    return num > 0 ? "positive" : "negative";
  }
};

const num1 = 3;
console.log(numCheck(num1));
```

Comment: There are other options, but what you have is the clearest IMO. (except, use `===`, not `==`)

Comment: would map be even more clear?? im inspired by the second solution here but not sure how it applies to my code. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18269354/13782899

Comment: `const numCheck = (num) => num === 0 ? 'zero' : num > 0 ? 'positive' : num < 0 ? 'negative' : 'undefined';`

Comment: @jazzfaz with the map method you mentioned you will need infinite amount of keys? the answers here give solution using ternary operator. thats the shortest i guess

Comment: @cmgchess i don't have infinite keys, but i couldn't figure out with map method how to use condition as a key, since the example was string match

Comment: @jazzfaz The mapping approach only works when you have exact values, so it could replicate `num == 0` but not `num > 0` (or `num < 0` for that matter)

Comment: aha i got it! so map only works for fixed key match..not conditions

Comment: `[100, 1, 0, -1, -100].map(x => !x ? "zero" : x > 0 ? "positive" : "negative");`

Answer (score 2):

In the solution below, the `numCheck()` method is tested by using the [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method, considering three possible situations.

```js
const numCheck = (num) => {
  return (num == 0) ? "zero" : ((num > 0) ? "positive" : "negative");
};

const numbers = [1, -1, 0];

console.log(numbers.map(number => numCheck(number)));
```

Comment: `numCheck()`
`>> "negative"` 

Answer (score 1):

you can do that, simply use [Math.sign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sign)  :

```js
const numCheck = n => ['negative','zero','positive'][1+Math.sign(n)]
 
console.log( numCheck( 4 ) ) 
console.log( numCheck( 0 ) ) 
console.log( numCheck( -3 ) )
```

Comment: haha this is not very readable but genius to think of!

Comment: @jazzfaz  Thanks :) ,hmm, i'm willing to admit it's unusual, but for me it's still readable, let's say it's just [thinking outside the box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thinking_outside_the_box#Nine_dots_puzzle) ?

Answer (score 0):

A shorter solution:

```js
var numCheck = (num) => num == 0 ? "zero" : num > 0 ? "positive" : "negative";
const num1 = 3;
console.log(numCheck(num1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Mister Jojo answer but without `Math.sign`

```js
const sign = x => ['negative','zero','positive'][1 + (x > 0) - (x < 0)]
 
console.log(sign(10))  // positive
console.log(sign(0))   // zero
console.log(sign(-20)) // negative
```