# Shorter way to return propertype enum in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function like this:

```
  public CustomerEditType(customer: Customer): CustomerEditType {
    if (customer.company) {
      if (customer.vatNumber) {
        return CustomerEditType.COMPANYVAT;
      } else {
        return CustomerEditType.COMPANYNOVAT;
      }
    } else {
      return CustomerEditType.PRIVATE;
    }
  }
```

The problem I have here is I don't know how to make this function shorter. Maybe an inline return statement?
How do I make this function shorter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the below code.

```
public CustomerEditType(customer: Customer): CustomerEditType {
    return customer.company ? (customer.vatNumber? CustomerEditType.COMPANYVAT : CustomerEditType.COMPANYNOVAT) : CustomerEditType.PRIVATE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public CustomerEditType(customer: Customer): CustomerEditType {
    return (customer.company? (customer.vatNumber? CustomerEditType.COMPANYVAT: CustomerEditType.COMPANYNOVAT) : CustomerEditType.PRIVATE));
}
```

Explanation:
this is a short if else statement:

```
boolenaStatement? ifTrue : else
```

Using this way you can nest statements:

```
statement1? (statement2? statement2True: statement2false) : statement1False
```

more info: [Shorthand for if-else statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269286/shorthand-for-if-else-statement)

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way would be:

```javascript
// shortest method
public CustomerEditType(customer: Customer): CustomerEditType {
  return (customer.company) ? ((customer.vatNumber) ? CustomerEditType.COMPANYVAT : CustomerEditType.COMPANYNOVAT) : CustomerEditType.PRIVATE;
}
```

For more information see:
[Javascript one line If...else...else if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29043135/javascript-one-line-if-else-else-if-statement)