# How to add-class and focus the children on keydown function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**MARKUP**

```
<ul class="focus">
    <li class="active"><a>Text 1</a></li>
    <li><a>Text 2</a></li>
    <li><a>Text 3</a></li>
    <li><a>Text 4</a></li>
    <li><a>Text 5</a></li>
    <li><a>Text 6</a></li>
    <li><a>Text 7</a></li>
    <li><a>Text 8</a></li>
    <li><a>Text 9</a></li>
    <li><a>Text 10</a></li>
    <li><a>Text 11</a></li>
    <li><a>Text 12</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.focus{
    height:60px;
    list-style-type:none;
    overflow:auto;
}
.focus li a {
}
.focus li.active{
    background:#f6f6f6;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$( ".focus" ).keydown(function() {
  if (  KeyCode == 40 ) {
      $(this).next(li).addClass('active').children(a).focus();
});
```

For the this markup i need to add a class active to the children li when a down arrow is pressed and the active li needs to get focused. I dont how to break the codes further can anyone explain. Thanks in advance.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4hd7w/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hd7w/7/)

You should add a `tabindex` to the `ul` (`<ul class="focus" tabindex='0'>`), and `href` attributes to the `a`, then use the following:

```
$(".focus").keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {    
        $('.active').removeClass('active').next('li').addClass('active').children('a').focus();
    }
});
```

To remove the outline (Chrome) on the `ul` when it has focus, you can use the CSS:

```
.focus:focus, .focus:active{
   outline:none;
}
```

Adding a `tabindex` allows the `ul` to be selectable and `key` events to be registered. Note you also want to enclose your selectors with speech marks.

---

### [Extended Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4hd7w/8/)

You can use the below to also scroll up down/loop through all items:

```
$(".focus").keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 40) {
        var next = $('.active').removeClass('active').next('li');
        next = next.length > 0 ? next : $('.focus li:eq(0)');
        next.addClass('active').children('a').focus();
    } else if (e.which == 38) {
        var prev = $('.active').removeClass('active').prev('li');
        prev = prev.length > 0 ? prev : $('.focus li').last();
        prev.addClass('active').children('a').focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: this one works fine and the one hard thing is when it reaches the last li and the down arrow pressed i could retain my focusin elements

Comment: @Benjamin - see the second example in the answer

Comment: Im new to jquery could u tell me why we use ? (symbol) in the middle of something.

Comment: @Benjamin - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864634/shorthand-if-else-statement-javascript

Comment: @SW4 while fiddling around, I made your code shorter.. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4hd7w/11/)

Comment: @SW4 yup.. updated again.. could be made more short I think.. [**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4hd7w/12/) :)

Comment: hi i need to implement this code in this fiddle will u able to help me http://jsfiddle.net/c9U3s/2/

Answer (score 2):

`ul` elements aren't *interactive*. This means that the `keydown` event will never fire on it. Your `a` elements are, however, so what you can do is assign your `keydown` event to your `a` elements instead.

Firstly you'll need to give your `a` elements a `href` attribute to make them interactive:

```
<li>
    <a href="#">Text 2</a>
</li>
```

Then modify your jQuery:

```
$('.focus').find('a').keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.which == 40)
        $(this).parent().next('li').addClass('active').children('a').focus();
});
```

Also you should use `event.which` instead of `KeyCode` as jQuery normalises this to work across all browsers: http://api.jquery.com/event.which/

[**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4hd7w/6/).

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the jQuery events documentation especially "event.which" 
http://api.jquery.com/event.which/

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var x=1;
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if ( code == 40 ) {
      $(".focus").children("li").removeClass('active');
      x++;
      if(x>  $(".focus li").length)
          x=1;
      $(".focus li:nth-child("+x+")").addClass('active');
  }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2e6F6/7/)

Comment: Are you sure this one works I don't think this one works even in the fiddle

Comment: yes, i just went to fiddle i found that it works why it didnt for you ?

Comment: Guess what trying it again and check whether it add the class active to the li it definitely not

Comment: here http://jsfiddle.net/56CB4/1/ see for your self btw im using firefox and it works fine for me O.o

Comment: dude this is really hard to believe it doesn't work . Check out the background color when li add class with action it should have the background value #f6f6f6

Comment: can you be more clear ? what (symbol) you mean ? $(document) ?? give me an example so i can help you :)

Comment: btw i just found out it dont work in chrome it might be only working in firefox

Comment: that what im talking abt i use chrome all the time can u able to fix that one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58598/discussion-between-benjamin-and-youness).